# Is it possible to have a compound Select Case statement containing the Case Else scenario?

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to do something like the following in VB utilizing the Case Else scenario in a compound statement (like falling through to a default in C#). Is this possible?

```
Select Case someString
    Case "UniqueScenario1","UniqueScenario2"
       DoUniqueAction();
    Case "Default", Else
       DoDefaultAction();
End Select
```

Comment: What's so bad in using `Select Case someString
            Case "UniqueScenario1", "UniqueScenario2"
                DoUniqueAction()
            Case "Default"
                DoDefaultAction()
            Case Else
                DoDefaultAction()
        End Select`?

Comment: It should be evident--I would not like to have to define the code in two places. I don't have to do it in C# and am wondering if there is a way for me to not have to do this in VB.

Comment: As mentioned below, this is not possible in VB.NET, but a C# `switch` and a VB.NET `Select..Case` are very different anyway. There are a lot of things that are not supported in C# `switch`es like ranges, comparison operators or `Is`(for type checks). This is one of the things that don't work in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what's the problem with using a new line and another `DoDefaultAction`:

```
Select Case someString
    Case "UniqueScenario1", "UniqueScenario2"
        DoUniqueAction()
    Case "Default"
        DoDefaultAction()
    Case Else
        DoDefaultAction()
End Select
```

However, if you want to do the same in `Case "Default"`*and* `Case Else` you could simply omit it:

```
Select Case someString
    Case "UniqueScenario1", "UniqueScenario2"
        DoUniqueAction()
    Case Else
        DoDefaultAction()
End Select
```

Comment: That will work, however I would prefer to call out in the code that there are certain "expected" values that should be handled the same way as unexpected values. That way when someone revisits the code it's more clear that certain values don't fall in this catch-all bucket and we don't have to rehash business logic rules.

Comment: @moarboilerplate: so basically, in pseudo code you want to say `if "Default" OrElse Whatever Then DoDefaultAction`? In my opinion it's even less readable than using a separate `If...ElseIf...Else`(similar to my first, repeating `Case`). On that way it's obvious that both cause the same action but that it's important to treat `"Default"` explicitly. That way is also  easier to debug and to maintain, for example if you want to change business logic or log them separately. However, it's not supported to use a specific value and also `Case Else` in the same line.